# Does g(n) ∈ O(f(n)) imply f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I am just trying to understand how Big O and Big Omega work. I know that Big O means no better than, and Big Omega means no worse than running times. So if I have a function *g*(*n*) such that *g*(*n*) = *O*(*f*(*n*)) then can I say that *f*(*n*) = Ω(*g*(*n*))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation-wise, it is better to write *g*(n) ∈ *O*(*f*(*n*)), because "*O*(*f*(*n*))" can be seen as the **set** of all functions that grow no faster than a multiple of *f*(*n*).

Let us restate the two relevant formal definitions used in complexity theory:

- *g*(n) ∈ *O*(*f*(*n*)) ⇔ ∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [|*g*(*n*)| ≤ *k*·|*f*(*n*)|]
- *f*(n) ∈ *Ω*(*g*(*n*)) ⇔ ∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*f*(*n*) ≥ *k*·*g*(*n*)]

If we can assume that *f* and *g* are non-negative functions (which is almost always the case for functions used in computer science), then we can drop the absolute value signs. Thus:

- *g*(n) ∈ *O*(*f*(*n*)) ⇔ ∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*g*(*n*) ≤ *k*·*f*(*n*)]
- *f*(n) ∈ *Ω*(*g*(*n*)) ⇔ ∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*f*(*n*) ≥ *k*·*g*(*n*)]

Next, flip the inequality on the second logical statement:

- *g*(n) ∈ *O*(*f*(*n*)) ⇔ ∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*g*(*n*) ≤ *k*·*f*(*n*)]
- *f*(n) ∈ *Ω*(*g*(*n*)) ⇔ ∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*k*·*g*(*n*) ≤ *f*(*n*)]

Now let's prove that the right-hand side of the first statement implies the right-hand side of the second statement:

1. Assume that ∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*g*(*n*) ≤ *k*·*f*(*n*)] is true.
2. Instantiate the *k*>0 that satisfies ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*g*(*n*) ≤ *k*·*f*(*n*)].
3. Let *k*ʹ = 1/*k*, which is legal because *k* ≠ 0.
4. Instantiate the *N*≥0 that satisfies ∀*n*≥*N* [*g*(*n*) ≤ *k*·*f*(*n*)].
5. Let *n* be an arbitrary number such that *n*≥*N*.
6. Then we have *g*(*n*) ≤ *k*·*f*(*n*).
7. Next we have *g*(*n*)/*k* ≤ *f*(*n*).
8. By substitution, we have *k*ʹ·*g*(*n*) ≤ *f*(*n*).
9. Because *n* is arbitrary, we derive that ∀*n*≥*N* [*k*ʹ·*g*(*n*) ≤ *f*(*n*)].
10. We derive that ∃*N*≥0 that satisfies ∀*n*≥*N* [*k*ʹ·*g*(*n*) ≤ *f*(*n*)].
11. We derive that ∃*kʹ*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*k*ʹ·*g*(*n*) ≤ *f*(*n*)].
12. We rename *kʹ* to *k*, so that ∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*k*·*g*(*n*) ≤ *f*(*n*)].
13. Thus [∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*g*(*n*) ≤ *k*·*f*(*n*)]] implies [∃*k*>0 ∃*N*≥0 ∀*n*≥*N* [*k*·*g*(*n*) ≤ *f*(*n*)]].
14. Therefore *g*(n) ∈ *O*(*f*(*n*)) implies *f*(n) ∈ *Ω*(*g*(*n*)), as wanted.